# How to pass data from github actions workflow to a JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-actions, devops

The goal is to read through all the commit's related to the PR to see if they contain keywords (e.g. feat, fix, BREAKING CHANGE, etc.). If they do, then I'll increment the version number of my application (e.g. 2.11.7).

I want to pass the github.event.commits to my JS file (where I actually update the version number). However, I can't figure out how to get the commit data to the JS file that my workflow runs.

```
name: update-version
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
    - closed

jobs: 
  if_merged:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true && (github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/test')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run script to update the version stored in package.json
        # How do I pass a github.event.commits to the below file?
        run: node ./shell-scripts/update-version.js github.event github.event.commits github.event.pull_request

      - run: |
          echo The version was updated
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions Bot"
          git config user.email "<>"
          git add -A
          git commit -m "updated version"
          git push
          echo The version update has been committed
```

UPDATE:
I can pass `github.event.pull_request` to the file. However, when I pass `github.event.commits`, it's null.
Same goes for `github.event`, which is strange because I can access pull_request from `github.event`?

Comment: You may pass it as an env var i.e. `env: COMMITS: ${{ github.event.commits }}` and fetch it from that env var. Or, you may store it in a file and read that in the script for further processing. Or, you can pass it as a command line argument and process that.

Comment: @Azeem why isn't github.events.commits or github.event getting passed through but github.event.pull_request is?

Comment: How are you passing it? I thought you already checked the correct fields of the payload that you need. According to its `pull_request` event payload, it has `commits` inside it i.e. `github.event.pull_request.commits`. See https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request. You can always check and verify the fields and values of a context by dumping it as JSON with `toJson` function e.g. `echo ${{ toJson(github) }}`.