# How do I get the git commits for my pull request in a workflow

Tags: node.js, github, yaml, github-actions, backend

I want to pass all commits associated to only this PR/Branch.
I've tried accessing `github.event.commits` and it was empty, the commits aren't located in `github.event.pull_request.GITHUB_HEAD_REF`. This is my workflow:

```
name: update-version
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
    - closed

jobs: 
  if_merged:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true && (github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/test')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run script to update the version stored in package.json
        # This didn't work, argument was empty: run: node ./shell-scripts/update-version.js github.event.commits
        # This worked, but the argument didn't contain commit data: node ./shell-scripts/update-version.js github.event.pull_request.GITHUB_HEAD_REF
        # This didn't worked, argument was empty even tho I can access .pull_request in the above example: node ./shell-scripts/update-version.js github.event
        run: node ./shell-scripts/update-version.js

      - run: |
          echo The version was updated
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions Bot"
          git config user.email "<>"
          git add -A
          git commit -m "updated version"
          git push
          echo The version update has been committed
```

Attempts:

1. This didn't work, argument was empty: `run: node ./shell-scripts/update-version.js github.event.commits`
2. This worked, but the argument didn't contain commit data: `run: node ./shell-scripts/update-version.js github.event.pull_request.GITHUB_HEAD_REF`
3. This didn't work, argument was empty even tho I can access `.pull_request` in the above example: `run: node ./shell-scripts/update-version.js github.event`
4. I also tried this command `git cherry -v github.event.pull_request.GITHUB_HEAD_REF.GITHUB_BASE_REF github.event.pull_request.GITHUB_HEAD_REF.GITHUB_HEAD_REF`. However, it passed each part of the command as separate arguments. I'm not sure how to store the results in an environment variable either.

---

Update:

I haven't fully written out my script yet becuase I need to first see how the commit array is structured. However, this is my plan:

- I'm going to look at each commit message
- Do a search through the message for a list of keywords: Fix/fixed, feat/feature, etc.
- Depending on the type of keyword and the quantity of them, I'm going to update the version "1.3.14". This is how updating the versioning will work:

  - Update the third digit for fixes: version `1.3.^`
  - Update the second digit for features: version `1.^.14`
  - Update first digit for breaking changes: version `^.3.14`

Comment: You can remove your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76534274/how-to-pass-data-from-github-actions-workflow-to-a-js-file) in favor of this. This one has more details.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? By "passing all commits", what are you implying? What does your script do? Please add this information in your question. In all your four cases, `${{..}}` is missing while accessing contexts. See [expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) for more details.

Comment: @Azeem I updated my comment, when I did use `${{...}}` and it still didn't work

Comment: What error did you get? You can also use GitHub CLI e.g. `gh pr view --json commits --jq '.commits' <PR_NUMBER>` to get the array of commits of a PR. See https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view for more details.